# Random letters showing in ppowershell script error making it so hard to find where the error stems from

Tags: powershell, shell, registry, windows-11, regedit

I keep receiving random letters powershell script error.
I made a changing mouse scheme script based on system os theme. I keep receiving random letters as shown in the image below when running the powershell script:
[image: Script Error]

This is my script:

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][int]$daySegment2,  # 0 = Day, 1 = Night
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][int]$daySegment4,  # -1 = N/A, 0 = Sunrise, 1 = Day, 2 = Sunset, 3 = Night
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][bool]$nightMode,   # True if night mode is enabled
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$imagePath # Path to current wallpaper image
)

$Location = "~\AppData\Local\WinDynamicDesktop\scripts\globalScripts\NightValue.xml"
$PreviousNightValue = Import-CliXml $Location

$Location2 = "~\AppData\Local\WinDynamicDesktop\scripts\globalScripts\StartValue.xml"
$StartValue = Import-CliXml $Location2

$NightValue = If ($nightMode) {1} Else {$daySegment2}

if ( ($NightValue -eq 0 -and $StartValue -eq 1) -or ($NightValue -ne $PreviousNightValue -and $StartValue -eq 0 -and $NightValue -eq 0))
{
$RegConnect = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]”CurrentUser”,”$env:COMPUTERNAME”)
$RegCursors = $RegConnect.OpenSubKey(“Control Panel\Cursors”,$true)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“”,”W11 Cursor Light HD v2.2 by Jepri Creations”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“AppStarting”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_light_v2.2\working.ani”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“Arrow”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_light_v2.2\pointer.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“Crosshair”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_light_v2.2\precision.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“Hand”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_light_v2.2\link.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“Help”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_light_v2.2\help.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“IBeam”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_light_v2.2\beam.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“No”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_light_v2.2\unavailable.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“NWPen”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_light_v2.2\handwriting.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“Person”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_light_v2.2\person.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“Pin”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_light_v2.2\pin.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“precisionhair”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_dark_v2.2\precision.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“SizeAll”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_light_v2.2\move.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“SizeNESW”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_light_v2.2\dgn2.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“SizeNS”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_light_v2.2\vert.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“SizeNWSE”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_light_v2.2\dgn1.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“SizeWE”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_light_v2.2\horz.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“UpArrow”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_light_v2.2\alternate.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“Wait”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_light_v2.2\busy.ani”)
$RegCursors.Close()
$RegConnect.Close()
$CSharpSig = @’
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SystemParametersInfo")]
public static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(
             uint uiAction,
             uint uiParam,
             uint pvParam,
             uint fWinIni);
‘@
$CursorRefresh = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $CSharpSig -Name WinAPICall -Namespace SystemParamInfo –PassThru
$CursorRefresh::SystemParametersInfo(0x0057,0,$null,0)
}
ElseIf (($NightValue -eq 1 -and $StartValue -eq 1) -or ($NightValue -ne $PreviousNightValue -and $StartValue -eq 0 -and $NightValue -eq 1))
{
$RegConnect = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]”CurrentUser”,”$env:COMPUTERNAME”)
$RegCursors = $RegConnect.OpenSubKey(“Control Panel\Cursors”,$true)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“”,”W11 Cursors Dark HD v2.2 by Jepri Creations”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“AppStarting”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_dark_v2.2\working.ani”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“Arrow”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_dark_v2.2\pointer.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“Crosshair”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_dark_v2.2\precision.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“Hand”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_dark_v2.2\link.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“Help”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_dark_v2.2\help.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“IBeam”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_dark_v2.2\beam.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“No”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_dark_v2.2\unavailable.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“NWPen”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_dark_v2.2\handwriting.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“Person”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_dark_v2.2\person.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“Pin”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_dark_v2.2\pin.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“precisionhair”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_dark_v2.2\precision.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“SizeAll”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_dark_v2.2\move.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“SizeNESW”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_dark_v2.2\dgn2.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“SizeNS”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_dark_v2.2\vert.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“SizeNWSE”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_dark_v2.2\dgn1.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“SizeWE”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_dark_v2.2\horz.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“UpArrow”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_dark_v2.2\alternate.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“Wait”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_dark_v2.2\busy.ani”)
$RegCursors.Close()
$RegConnect.Close()
$CSharpSig = @’
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SystemParametersInfo")]
public static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(
                uint uiAction,
                uint uiParam,
                uint pvParam,
                uint fWinIni);
‘@
$CursorRefresh = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $CSharpSig -Name WinAPICall -Namespace SystemParamInfo –PassThru
$CursorRefresh::SystemParametersInfo(0x0057,0,$null,0)
}

$StartValue = 0
if (($NightValue -ne $PreviousNightValue))
{
    $NightValue | Export-Clixml -path $Location
}

if ($StartValue -ne 0)
{
    $StartValue | Export-Clixml -path $Location2
}
```

I tried removing some parts of the script, I think the problem stems for registry editing. But had no luck. the error kept showing no matter what I delete.

I tried putting the
$PSStyle.OutputRendering='PlainText'
at the top of my script, I received the same error.
I tried setting the NO_COLOR to 1 inside my script. Did not fix the issue.
I don't have access to the application that runs the script, I just can edit my script.
BTW, that's started happening when the software started using PowerShell 7 instead of windows PowerShell(V5) I started getting this error.

Comment: It looks to me like you have an *encoding* issue rather than a coding issue... :D What is the encoding of your `.ps1` file?

Comment: utf 8
this is the error i'm receiving after running the script in utf 8 encoding:
https://imgur.com/EOkjInu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: The following applies to **[PowerShell (Core)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) v7.2+**:

What you're seeing are **ANSI / VT (Virtual Terminal) *escape sequences*** that are typically **used to make *terminals* render text *with formatting*, notably *colored***.

**If you render strings containing such escape sequences *verbatim*, such as via a message box, you'll get garbled text** as in your screenshot, so **you'll need to instruct PowerShell *not* to use these escape sequences**.

Since it looks like you're calling your PowerShell script from the *outside*, via the [`pwsh.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the Windows PowerShell CLI, a simple way to instruct PowerShell *not* to use these escape sequences it to **define the `NO_COLOR` environment variable** (with *any* value, but `1` makes conceptual sense) ***before* calling `pwsh.exe`**.<sup>[1]</sup>

An alternative is to **execute `$PSStyle.OutputRendering='PlainText'`**:

- Either: as part of a `-Command` (`-c`) argument passed to `pwsh.exe`
- Or: By placing this call at the *top of your script*.

For more information, see the conceptual [about_ANSI_Terminals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_ANSI_Terminals) help topic.

---

**Demonstration of the problem**:

```
# Call the PowerShell (Core) 7.2+ CLI and provoke an error,
# then render the output via a message box:
(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell).Popup(
  (pwsh -c '1 / 0')
)
```

Result - note the garbled text:

[image: screenshot with garbled text]

The problem goes away if you define `NO_COLOR` first:

```
$env:NO_COLOR=1
(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell).Popup(
  (pwsh -c '1 / 0')
)
```

Result - no more garbled text:

[image: screenshot - cleaned-up text]

---

<sup>[1] If you define it for the *calling* process, the `pwsh` child process will *inherit* it. Unlike the `$PSStyle.OutputRendering` setting, `NO_COLOR` must already exist when the `pwsh` process is created in order to be effective. In cases where you're calling from a *Unix* shell, you can define the environmant variable in a *command-scoped* way, e.g. `NO_COLOR=1 pwsh -c '1 / 0'`</sup>

Comment: I tried putting the
$PSStyle.OutputRendering='PlainText'
at the top of my script, I received the same error.
I tried setting the NO_COLOR to 1 inside my script. Did not fix the issue.
I don't have access to the application that runs the script, I just can edit my script.
BTW, that's correct only when the software start using powershell 7 instead of windows powershell(V5) I started getting this error.

Comment: @EyalCohen, the `NO_COLOR` environment variable must be set from _outside_ the PowerShell process, i.e. it must already exist when the `pwsh` process is created. Do you have a way to do that?

Comment: @EyalCohen, also, I just tried in v7.2.9 and v7.3.3: placing `$PSStyle.OutputRendering='PlainText'` at the top of a script works for me.

Comment: I am still having the same issue. I feel this is starting to become XY problem.
check the image below:
https://imgur.com/exsmrGZ
Btw, when running the script in powershell ISE or from teminal no errors are thrown. Only when the 3rd party application runs the script.

Comment: Adding the line $PSStyle.OutputRendering='PlainText' throws an error in the terminal/ISE:
The property 'OutputRendering' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At line:1 char:1
+ $PSStyle.OutputRendering='PlainText'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound
 
https://imgur.com/q9Op5bn

Comment: @EyalCohen, save your `.ps1` file with UTF-8 encoding, which PowerShell (Core) now assumes by default. For PowerShell (Core), you don't need a BOM, but if you want Windows PowerShell to read the file correctly too, use _UTF-8 with BOM_.

Comment: @EyalCohen, you cannot run code that uses _PowerShell (Core)_-only features such as `$PSStyle` in the _ISE_, which supports _Windows PowerShell_ only. Please see the next comment for standard advice.

Comment: As an aside: The PowerShell ISE is [no longer actively developed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support) and [there are reasons not to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375) (bottom section), notably not being able to run PowerShell (Core) 6+. The actively developed, cross-platform editor that offers the best PowerShell development experience is [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with its [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell).

Comment: I just moved to visual studio code to check my problems. Thanks for all of your suggestions you helped me alot. I never knew PowerShell ISE is limited to powershell 5.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @EyalCohen; my pleasure. `$PSVersionTable` shows you what PowerShell version / edition you're running.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252144/discussion-between-eyal-cohen-and-mklement0).